# C# Azure upload file error The specified blob or block content is invalid

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, upload, async-await

I'm uploading files to azure storage.

```
public class AzureBlob : ICloudBlob
{
    private string _fileName;
    public string FileName
    {
        get => _fileName;
        set
        {
            _fileName = value;
            _cloudBlockBlob = CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(value);
        }
    }
    public CloudBlobContainer CloudBlobContainer { get; set; }
    private CloudBlockBlob _cloudBlockBlob;

    public async Task UploadChunksFromPathAsync(string path, long fileLength)
    {
        const int blockSize = 256 * 1024;
        var bytesToUpload = fileLength;
        long bytesUploaded = 0;
        long startPosition = 0;

        var blockIds = new List<string>();
        var index = 0;

        do
        {
            var bytesToRead = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToUpload);
            var blobContents = new byte[bytesToRead];

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                fs.Position = startPosition;
                fs.Read(blobContents, 0, (int) bytesToRead);
            }

            var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString("d6")));

            blockIds.Add(blockId);
            await _cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, new MemoryStream(blobContents), null);

            bytesUploaded += bytesToRead;
            bytesToUpload -= bytesToRead;
            startPosition += bytesToRead;
            index++;
        } while (bytesToUpload > 0);

        await _cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds);   
    }
}
```

This works fine for one file upload, multiple file uploads calling this method one after the other throws a 400 error on `_cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync` with the azure error being

> The specified blob or block content is invalid.

**If I remove the await keyword on `_cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync` it works completely fine.**

The blockIds are all of the same length. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

Calling code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromBody] UploadViewModel model)
{
    var audioBlob = _cloudStorage.GetBlob(CloudStorageType.Audio, model.AudioName);

    await audioBlob.UploadChunksFromPathAsync(model.AudioPath, model.FileLength);

    return Ok();
}
```

Storage:

```
public enum CloudStorageType
{
    Audio,
    Image,
}

public class AzureStorage : ICloudStorage
{
    public IDictionary<CloudStorageType, ICloudBlob> CloudBlobs { get; set; }

    public AzureStorage(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configuration["ConnectionStrings:StorageConnectionString"]);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobs = new Dictionary<CloudStorageType, ICloudBlob>();

        foreach (CloudStorageType cloudStorageType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CloudStorageType)))
        {
            CloudBlobs[cloudStorageType] = new AzureBlob(cloudStorageType.ToString().ToLower(), blobClient);
        }
    }

    public ICloudBlob GetBlob(CloudStorageType cloudStorageType, string fileName)
    {
        CloudBlobs[cloudStorageType].FileName = fileName;

        return CloudBlobs[cloudStorageType];
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
var azureStorage = new AzureStorage(_configuration);

// Add application services.
services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage>(azureStorage);
```

Comment: Can you also share the code that is calling this method?

Comment: @GauravMantri Done. I call this upload action for each file upload that the user uploads (multiple is possible) one after the other. I do it this way so I can show a progress bar for each file upload.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating `audioBlob` outside of your upload method (I mean `UploadChunksFromPathAsync` method)? Will each `audioBlob` instance represent a different blob name?

Comment: @GauravMantri I create two blobs in my startup.cs. An audio blob that contains all audio files for my application and an images blob that contains the cover images for the audio files. Is this why it's failing? I figured it was better to do it this way rather than create blobs everywhere in my code.

Comment: I think you're confusing `blob` with `container`. From your description, you're actually creating 2 containers at the time of startup (which is perfectly fine). Can you share the code for `GetBlob`? Also please share how you're getting `_cloudBlockBlob` in your `UploadChunksFromPathAsync` method.

Comment: @GauravMantri Added everything that should be relevant. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri Figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** The reason was actually because half way through the download the blob was being overwritten by the next file. Basically create a new blob each upload so this doesn't happen.

Figured it out. The first download would work fine, however the second download would throw the error **if** the previous download had not been finished yet because that block blob was already in use downloading other blocks.

The fix was to create a new block blob for each download instead of just using one.

```
public async Task UploadChunksFromPathAsync(string path, long fileLength)
{
    var cloudBlockBlob = CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);

    const int blockSize = 256 * 1024;
    var bytesToUpload = fileLength;
    long bytesUploaded = 0;
    long startPosition = 0;

    var blockIds = new List<string>();
    var index = 0;

    do
    {
        var bytesToRead = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToUpload);
        var blobContents = new byte[bytesToRead];

        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            fs.Position = startPosition;
            fs.Read(blobContents, 0, (int) bytesToRead);
        }

        var blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString("d6")));

        blockIds.Add(blockId);
        await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockAsync(blockId, new MemoryStream(blobContents), null);

        bytesUploaded += bytesToRead;
        bytesToUpload -= bytesToRead;
        startPosition += bytesToRead;
        index++;
    } while (bytesToUpload > 0);

    await cloudBlockBlob.PutBlockListAsync(blockIds);   
}
```